# Tile based map editor: Scrolling: Generating new Image's while doing so locks up the application for some time

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, image

I'm currently working on a tile based map editor, focusing to get scrolling working exactly how I want. That's where I experience some troubles. While scrolling, images get generated to display the new content as you scroll around. This works fine till about 200 images (`System.Windows.Controls.Image`) being generated at a new side (simple maps, not complicated).

Whenever about 1000 images (or a lot more if you scroll faster..) get generated on the side, the application will hang for some time, depending on how rapid you scroll etc.

The cause of this temporarily hangup is always caused by this line. Removing this line eliminates the "lag" fully (but obviously does not give the wanted result):

```
img.Source = it.GetFullSpriteSource(0);
```

That method generates an ImageSource, or returns the ImageSource stored in a variable if already generated. The problem lies not in this method, since the following scenario gives the same problem.

```
public static ImageSource yellowimg;
[...]
System.Drawing.Bitmap derp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(32, 32);
using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(derp))
    g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 32, 32);
yellowimg = Utilities.ToImgSource(derp);
[...]
img.Source = yellowimg;
```

So the problem *probably* lies in the fact I assign the ImageSource.

I am generating an ImageSource out of a Bitmap like this, might be relevant:

```
public static ImageSource ToImgSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
      bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
      BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

---

I have also tried generation in a seperate Thread (background generation), but this results in the following error, trying to read the ImageSource from another thread.

`The calling thread cannot access the object because different thread owns it`

---

What are things I could try?

Keep in mind I'm not advanced with WPF (Recently started) and I have barely any knowledge about `ImageSource`.

Thanks,

~ Tgys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an ImageSource from a System.Drawing.Bitmap you should use [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). If you have to draw complicated drawing into the bitmap, you would have to draw into the [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx) of a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) and render that DrawingVisual into a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx),

When you create ImageSource objects in a separate thread, you have to call their [Freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) method before using them in the UI.

Comment: I'm drawing the whole scene by using a lot of `System.Windows.Controls.Image` instances, not into a single bitmap. The used bitmaps are static. I'm not sure if I misunderstand you or you've misunderstood me..

Comment: I was saying that you should not at all use System.Drawing.Bitmap as you do in `ToImgSource`, since that is not WPF and requires some GDI interop.

Comment: I see, but does this cause the lag? As `ToImgSource` is only called once to generate the ImageSource, not again every time a new image is added. Anyway, I'll be trying out WriteableBitmap to begin with.. :]

Comment: Ah, i see. You might perhaps follow your multithreading approach with frozen images.

Comment: I'm loading the images using the secondary thread now which works thanks to .Freeze();